# Clearing localStorage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there any way to reset/clear the browser's `localStorage` in javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1623, accepted):

Use this to clear localStorage:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: @BakedInhalf not at all. Maybe your app sets it over again?

Comment: I call localStorage.clear() when my app starts up, but even if I close the browser, clear cache, etc., the data are still there.  I know this because I have set an "instance" property on my model to a random number on initialize, and, for a given id, the instance property is always the same.

Comment: @digital-plane Will this clear the local storage from a specific domain or all the storage?

Comment: It should be more obvious. `.clear()` could mean anything!

Comment: `clear()` will remove all localStorage keys and values from the specific domain you are on. Javascript is unable to get localStorage values from any other domains due to CORS.

Comment: @BakedInhalf is right, it stays until you hard refresh the page. When you clear your localStorage and fill it right after, it kind of restore the previous content and adds you new item to it. When you clear your localStorage and doing a hardrefresh, it is empty and you can start filling it again.

Comment: It is notable that if you are loading an html file directly from your hard drive (e.g. not running the code via a local web server) it will clear ALL local storage.

Answer (score 266):

If you want to remove a specific Item or variable from the user's local storage, you can use

```
localStorage.removeItem("name_of_localStorage_variable_to_remove");
```

Comment: Hi, @Ajeet If I don't want to remove for a particular item then is there a way to do it too? For example 'removeItemNotIn(key)', 'remove all except for a defined key'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @Shadow If I don't want to remove for a particular item then is there a way to do it too? For example 'removeItemNotIn(key)', 'remove all except for a defined key'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured out a solution for my problem:- 

if(localStorage.getItem(particularKey) == null){
   localStorage.clear();   
  }  
But if you have a better solution then do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @learner So you want to **remove  all keys except a particular key**, right?
For that you can do something like this 
`var key;
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  key = localStorage.key(i);

  if(key != particularKey){
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}`

Comment: Also possible: getting the value, clearing and setting the value again, more versatile. `let tmp = localStorage.getItem('<your-name>'); localStorage.clear(); localStorage.setItem('<your-name>')`

Answer (score 130):

```
window.localStorage.clear(); //try this to clear all local storage
```

Answer (score 20):

If you need to clear the local storage data use:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

To remove a particular item from the local storage use :

```
localStorage.removeItem('Item')
```

Answer (score 16):

Localstorage is attached on the global `window`. When we log localstorage in the chrome devtools we see that it has the following APIs:

[image]

We can use the following API's for deleting items:

1. `localStorage.clear()`: Clears the whole localstorage
2. `localStorage.removeItem('myItem')`: To remove individual items

Answer (score 14):

Here is a function that will allow you to remove all localStorage items with exceptions. You will need [jQuery](https://jquery.com) for this function. You can [download the gist](https://gist.github.com/christianjuth/8161d1161668e021a580).

You can call it like this

```
let clearStorageExcept = function(exceptions) {
  let keys = [];
  exceptions = [].concat(exceptions); // prevent undefined

  // get storage keys
  $.each(localStorage, (key) => {
    keys.push(key);
  });

  // loop through keys
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    let deleteItem = true;

    // check if key excluded
    for (let j = 0; j < exceptions.length; j++) {
      let exception = exceptions[j];
      if (key == exception) {
        deleteItem = false;
      }
    }

    // delete key
    if (deleteItem) {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Weird thing is that `undefined` is a valid key for `setItem` and `getItem`

Comment: @ebob Yes, it may seem weird, but no, really it is not. localStorage functions in a similar fashion to objects in that the keys are converted to strings. For example, using undefined as a key like this: `localStorage.setItem(undefined, 'example Txt!')`, will actuall store it under the key called `'undefined'` as you can see when you run the following code. `console.log(localStorage.getItem('undefined'))`  will output `example Txt!`.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to clear all item you stored in **localStorage** then

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Use this for clear all stored key.

If you want to clear/remove only specific key/value then you can use **removeItem(key)**.

```
localStorage.removeItem('yourKey');
```

Answer (score 9):

```
localStorage.clear();
```

or

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

to clear particular item

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("item_name");
```

> To remove particular value by id :

```
var item_detail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key_name")) || [];           
            $.each(item_detail, function(index, obj){
                if (key_id == data('key')) {
                    item_detail.splice(index,1);
                    localStorage["key_name"] = JSON.stringify(item_detail);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

First things first, you need to check to make sure that localStorage is enabled. I would recommend doing it like this:

```
var localStorageEnabled = false;
try { localStorageEnabled = !!localStorage; } catch(e) {};
```

Yes, you can (in some cases) just check to see if the localStorage is a member of the window object. However, there are iframe sandboxing options (among other things) that will throw an exception if you even attempt to access the index 'localStorage'. Thus, for best-practices reasons, this is the best way to check to see if the localStorage is enabled. Then, you can just clear the localStorage like so.

```
if (localStorageEnabled) localStorage.clear();
```

For example, you could clear the localStorage after an error occurs in webkit browsers like so.

```
// clears the local storage upon error
if (localStorageEnabled)
  window.onerror = localStorage.clear.bind(localStorage);
```

In the above example, you need the `.bind(window)` because without it, the `localStorage.clear` function will run in the context of the `window` object, instead of the `localStorage` object making it silently fail. To demonstrate this, look at the below example:

```
window.onerror = localStorage.clear;
```

is the same as:

```
window.onerror = function(){
    localStorage.clear.call(window);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code here you give a list of strings of keys that you don't want to delete, then it filters those from all the keys in local storage then deletes the others.

```
const allKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);

const toBeDeleted = allKeys.filter(value => {
  return !this.doNotDeleteList.includes(value);
});

toBeDeleted.forEach(value => {
  localStorage.removeItem(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To clear sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Comment: the question says "localstorage" not "sessionstorage", these two are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for a way to clear the localStorage whenever a browser tab is closed, the below code works. (sample use case: keep some copied data in localStoarge, to paste on another tab - but at the same time, needs the cache to not appear on new tabs, whenever all the previous tabs gets closed)

```js
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  // get localStorage item with specified key
  const storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MY_KEY'));
  // clear cache if exists
  if (!isNil(storage)) localStorage.removeItem('MY_KEY');
};
```

It adds an eventListener to the window, to detect tab closing and just before closed, it clears the tab's localStorage (of specified key). It will not clear localStorage (of the same key) on other tabs.

This is a great solution, if we want to clear localStorage only in the closed tab, and keep the localStorage (of the same key) on other tabs intact.

So that,

1. as long as a user keeps one tab opened, the user can leverage the localStorage cache, and
2. after all the tabs are closed, the localStorage will not appear on new
   tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code that will clear localstorage stored in your browser by using javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

if(localStorage) { // Check if the localStorage object exists

    localStorage.clear()  //clears the localstorage

} else {

    alert("Sorry, no local storage."); //an alert if localstorage is non-existing
}

</script>
```

To confirm if localstorage is empty use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check if the localStorage object exists
if(localStorage) {

    alert("Am still here, " + localStorage.getItem("your object name")); //put the object name
} else {
    alert("Sorry, i've been deleted ."); //an alert
}

</script>
```

if it returns null then your localstorage is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Manual Button:

```
<script>
function ask() {
if (confirm('Clear localStorage?') == true) {
localStorage.clear()
location.reload()
}
else {
alert('Nothing happend')
}
}
}
</script>
<style>
button {border-width:0px;background-color:#efefef;padding:5px;width:5cm;margin:5px;}
</style>
<button onclick=ask()>Clear localStorage</button>
```

Comment: Could do with an explanation