# Local Storage to hold form N pages data until final submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

My scenario: I have an application that is 9 pages long for a total of about 125 inputs of varying types and sizes (only input, textarea, radio, and selects).  I'd like to use local storage to save the form values.  The user can move between the pages (e.g. to review before submitting the application) so I don't want to clear the local storage until they submit the application and if they change from page to page, the form should reload its values from local storage.  Once they submit the form, then I'll clear the local storage but until then, the local storage should be retained.

I found this great [jquery plugin](http://shaneriley.tumblr.com/post/1729353009/saving-form-state-with-jquery-and-localstorage) and a [demo page](http://shaneriley.com/jquery/remember_state/) which appears to almost do what I'm looking for - well, with two exceptions:

1) The plugin prompts the user if they want to restore their previously entered info which I'd prefer to not have (I'd rather have the data just be there).  My navigational buttons at the bottom of the form are simply "Previous" and "Continue" (on the first page, it is just "Continue" and on the last page they would be "Previous" and "Submit Application").

2) The plugin will prompt the user even if there is no data to load (this would be a non-issue if I can just have it load data if there is any and skip it if there is not).  For example, the very first visit to the page will prompt the user to restore previously entered data.

Here is a link to the [jquery.remember-state.js](http://shaneriley.com/jquery/remember_state/jquery.remember-state.js) used in the demo page.

=======================================================
I took the demo above and tweaked the jquery.remember-state.js to ***try*** and make it do what I need but it isn't working correctly.
Here is my ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Excalibur/KmkH5/4/)).
**NOTE 1:** the jsFiddle is meant to just show my code and is not a necessarily a working example in the jsFiddle environment.  If you copy the code to your local environment, you should be able to access the console.log to see if/what gets saved to the localStorage.
**NOTE 2:** S.O.  wants formatted code inline so I'll see what I can do to make it format correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>LocalStorage and Unload State Save</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jQueryPlugins/RememberState/form.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- use the modified jquery.remember-state.js code in the JavaScript panel instead
       the script tag below is the original js file
  <script src="http://shaneriley.com/jquery/remember_state/jquery.remember-state.js"></script>-->
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
(function($) {
  /* jQuery form remember state plugin
     Name: rememberState
     Version: 1.3
     Description: When called on a form element, localStorage is used to
     remember the values that have been input up to the point of either
     saving or unloading. (closing window, navigating away, etc.) If
     localStorage isn't available, nothing is bound or stored.
     The plugin looks for an element with a class of remember_state to show
     a note indicating there is stored data that can be repopulated by clicking
     on the anchor within the remember_state container. If the element doesn't
     exist, it is created and prepended to the form.
     Usage: $("form").rememberState("my_object_name");
     Notes: To trigger the deletion of a form's localStorage object from
     outside the plugin, trigger the reset_state event on the form element
     by using $("form").trigger("reset_state");
  */
  if (!window.localStorage || !window.JSON) {
    if (console && console.log) {
      !window.localStorage && console.log("ERROR: you browser does not support" +
        " localStorage (use this polyfill https://gist.github.com/350433)");
      !window.JSON&& console.log("ERROR: you browser does not support" +
        " JSON (use this polyfill http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/)");
    }
    return $.fn.rememberState = function() { return this; };
  }

  var remember_state = {
    name: "rememberState",
    clearOnSubmit: false, //default was true;
    //  ****************************
    /*noticeDialog: (function() {
        return $("<p />", {"class": "remember_state"})
        .html('Do you want to <a href="#">restore your previously entered info</a>?');
    })(),*/
    //  ****************************    
    ignore: null,
    noticeSelector: ".remember_state",
    use_ids: false,
    objName: false,
    clickNotice: function(e) {
      var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(e.data.instance.objName)),
          $f = $(this).closest("form"),
          $e;
      for (var i in data) {
        $e = $f.find("[name=\"" + data[i].name + "\"]");
        if ($e.is(":radio, :checkbox")) {
          $e.filter("[value=" + data[i].value + "]").prop("checked", true);
        }
        else if ($e.is("select")) {
          $e.find("[value=" + data[i].value + "]").prop("selected", true);
        }
        else {
          $e.val(data[i].value);
        }
        $e.change();
      }
      e.data.instance.noticeDialog.remove();
      e.preventDefault();
    },
    chooseStorageProp: function() {
      if (this.$el.length > 1) {
        if (console && console.warn) {
          console.warn("WARNING: Cannot process more than one form with the same" +
            " object. Attempting to use form IDs instead.");
        }
        this.objName = this.$el.attr("id");
      }
    },
    errorNoID: function() {
      if (console && console.log) {
        console.log("ERROR: No form ID or object name. Add an ID or pass" +
          " in an object name");
      }
    },
    saveState: function(e) {
      var instance = e.data.instance;
      var values = instance.$el.serializeArray();
      // jQuery doesn't currently support datetime-local inputs despite a
      // comment by dmethvin stating the contrary:
      // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5667
      // Manually storing input type until jQuery is patched
      instance.$el.find("input[type='datetime-local']").each(function() {
        var $i = $(this);
        values.push({ name: $i.attr("name"), value: $i.val() });
      });
      values = instance.removeIgnored(values);

      values.length && internals.setObject(instance.objName, values);
    },
    save: function() {
      var instance = this;
      if (!this.saveState) {
        instance = this.data(remember_state.name);
      }
      instance.saveState({ data: { instance: instance } });
    },
    removeIgnored: function(values) {
      if (!this.ignore) { return values; }
      $.each(this.ignore, function(i, name) {
        $.each(values, function(j, input) {
          if (name === input.name) { delete values[j]; }
        });
      });
      return values;
    },
    init: function() {
      var instance = this;
        //  ****************************
     /* if (instance.noticeDialog.length && instance.noticeDialog.jquery) {
        instance.noticeDialog.find("a").bind("click." + instance.name, {
          instance: instance
        }, instance.clickNotice);
      }*/
        //  ****************************

      instance.chooseStorageProp();
      if (!instance.objName) {
        instance.errorNoID();
        return;
      }

      if (localStorage[instance.objName]) {
            //  **************************** 
        /*if (instance.noticeDialog.length && typeof instance.noticeDialog === "object") {
          instance.noticeDialog.prependTo(instance.$el);
        }
        else {
          instance.$el.find(instance.noticeSelector).show();
        }*/
            //  ****************************
      }
      if (instance.clearOnSubmit) {
        instance.$el.bind("submit." + instance.name, function() {
          instance.$el.trigger("reset_state");
          $(window).unbind("unload." + instance.name);
        });
      }

      instance.$el.bind("reset_state." + instance.name, function() {
          localStorage.removeItem(instance.objName);
      });
        //  ****************************
      /*$(window).bind("unload." + instance.name, { instance: instance }, instance.saveState);
      instance.$el.find(":reset").bind("click.remember_state", function() {
          $(this).closest("form").trigger("reset_state");
      });*/

    }
  };

  var internals = {
    setObject: function(key, value) { localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value); },
    getObject: function(key) { return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]); },
    createPlugin: function(plugin) {
      $.fn[plugin.name] = function(opts) {
        var $els = this,
            method = $.isPlainObject(opts) || !opts ? "" : opts;
        if (method && plugin[method]) {
          plugin[method].apply($els, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if (!method) {
          $els.each(function(i) {
            var plugin_instance = $.extend(true, {
              $el: $els.eq(i)
            }, plugin, opts);
            $els.eq(i).data(plugin.name, plugin_instance);
            plugin_instance.init();
          });
        }
        else {
          $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.' + plugin.name);
        }
        return $els;
      };
    }
  };

  internals.createPlugin(remember_state);
})(jQuery);

});//]]>  

</script>
  <script>
  var thisPage = 'page1';   //defines the variable to use for local storage
    $(function() {
      $("form")
        .rememberState({objName: thisPage})
        .submit(function() {localStorage.setItem(thisPage, $(this).serializeArray());
        return true;
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="page2.cfm">
    <fieldset>
      <dl>

        <dt><label for="first_name">First Name</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" /></dd>
        <dt><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" /></dd>
      </dl>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="actions">
      <input type="submit" value="Continue" />

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should also add that I'm not married to this plugin so I'm open to other plugins.  While a database is available, the client would prefer to not use the database for fear of hacking attempts.  The form will be emailed upon completion.  This is for a small non-profit group.

Comment: why you need plugin? why not use localStorage API directly?

Comment: From what I've read, you can only save data locally as field1=value1, filed2=value2, etc.  In some of the plugins I've found, you can assign something like page1=[field1=value1, filed2=value2, etc], page2=[field1=value1, filed2=value2, etc.] which would just allow for a more organized localStorage.  I plugin isn't required, I just thought it might be easier.

Comment: Using JSON serialization, you can store any plain object. It is easy and all problem will be solved. BTW, Using localStorage is incorrect, sessionStorage have to be used here.

Comment: @KyawTun - Why do you say sessionStorage is correct?  I wanted to provide the user the option of coming back later to fill in the rest of the application and with my limited knowledge of using storage is that local would be more persistent.  Am I incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was going to be tougher than it was.  Here is the solution I came up with:

On the form page when the submit button is pressed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function()    {
var thisPageID = 'page1';  // each page gets its own    
    $('form').submit(function() {    
        var formFields = $(this).serialize();    
        localStorage.setItem(thisPageID, formFields);    
        data = localStorage.getItem(thisPageID);    
        return true;    
    });    
});    
</script>
```

Then on the final page, I retrieve the data for each page by its page id from the local storage and populate my div tags with the data.

```
function getLocalData(id){
    var ApplicantData;
    ApplicantData = localStorage.getItem(id);
    if (ApplicantData){
        $.each(ApplicantData.split('&'), function (index, elem) {
            var vals = elem.split('=');
            var $div = $("#"+vals[0]);
            var separator = '';
            //  console.log($div);
            if ($div.html().length > 0) {
                separator = ', ';
            }
            $div.html($div.html() + separator + decodeURIComponent(vals[1].replace(/\+/g, '  ')));
        });             
    }
}
```

Some of the Articles that helped me (some SO, some external):
 - [Clear localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clear-localstorage)
 - http://www.simonbingham.me.uk/index.cfm/main/post/uuid/using-html5-local-storage-and-jquery-to-persist-form-data-47
 - http://www.thomashardy.me.uk/using-html5-localstorage-on-a-form

There were more but this is all I still had open in tabs.