# remove value from localstorage javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to remove item from **localStorage** in javasscript but it doesn't work.

It only works manually for the sequence of the following events

```
Right click --> Inspect element --> Resources --> localStorage --> Right click --> Delete
```

I tried:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

and

```
localStorage.removeItem(key); // the key is the link of the page and 
                              // the value is the selected word in the page
```

and both didn't work, I can save item using `localStorage.setItem(key, vaule)` and get items from localStorage using `localStorage.getItem(key)` but I can't remove them.

Comment: a code example that isn't working would help us help you.

Comment: this is the only thing is not working , i want to remove the old values and put another each time i use this "function" so everything is perfect unless localStorage.clear(), it won't remove anything

Answer (score 4):

what your looking for is this:

```
deleter void removeItem(DOMString key);
```

You could implement this like so:

```
localStorage.removeItem(key)
```

Everything about local storage can be found [here on the W3 html5 spec for web storage.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute)

You may find this [document more helpful as it goes into more explanation.](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

*Local storage is not a finished spec and these could change.

Comment: the first one after it i can't save values anymore. and the second one didn't work. in my code i want to remove the values to set another value. thank u i will try to check the wensite

Answer (score -2):

localStorage.clear without the () currently works in major browsers.

Comment: Does it? `localStorage.clear` isn't a function call.  `localStorage.clear()` **is**.  And since [Clear localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7667958/691711) opts for `()`, I think that might be correct.