# How to destroy a localStorage item in Angular?

Tags: angular, local-storage

I want to delete or destroy my localStorage content whenever I route to a different component. I want to achieve this so as to avoid the localStorage variable from storing previous values even tho new values are coming in.

Am I on the right path?

**Game Component**

```
export class Game implements OnDestroy{    
    constructor(){   
        this.currentGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'));  
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){     
        this.currentGame = null;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove value from localstorage javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864256/remove-value-from-localstorage-javascript)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

you can use

```
localStorage.removeItem('currentGame');
```

Alternatively, you can also clear the whole localStorage with

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194979/discussion-between-abhi-and-sam).

Comment: Can we write localStorage.getItem and localStorage.removeItem in same page? Because I have written it. But I'm removing localStorage on click of a button but the item is getting removed without clicking the button. May be on page load it is getting removed.

Comment: @Kalyan it looks like your code is executed on page load. Maybe put `alert("I'm beeing executed");` just before removing the item to find out ;-)

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Yes my code is executing on page load... how to handle this?

Comment: @Kalyan You might have had a wrong ```type``` of your ```button``` or even no type at all. Try using ```type="button"```