# Angular: Clear LocalStorage on First Deployment

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, angular10

Is there a way in Angular to clear All Local Storage or at least ones particular to the application through maybe ng build, or Angular deployment, or through Angular code itself? This inthrough in Chrome F12 Local Storage.

This is the code base,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43637348/14432516

```
localStorage.removeItem('currentProduct');
localstorage.clear();
```

However, I need to to Detect First Deployment in Angular. How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your app version at your `environment.appVersion` on app load store that value to your local `localStorage` and on your app load get version from local storage if that version exist check if that version is the same as version in `environment.appVersion`. When they are different clear `localStorage`. on every deploy update your `environment.appVersion`.