# Twitter typeahead .js file not updating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead

I am currently in the process of switching form BootsTrap 2.3 to Bootstrap 3.0.
As we all know, there is no typeahead in the bootstrap 3.0 so I am using the twitter one:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/

I am able to query but for some reason, the query is not being updated...

Here is the code:

```
    $('.typeahead').typeahead([
  {
    name: 'users',
    prefetch: '../user/generate-users-typeahead',
    remote: '../user/generate-users-typeahead',
    limit: 5
  },
])
```

For example, if we start entering Exa there will still be results with the username Admin for example...

Any ideas why it is doing that?

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: Maybe your localStorage contains "old" data, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clear-localstorage

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... I thought the typeahead will automatically clear those?!?!?!?

Comment: no it store the data (json) in the localstorage. You could set a ttl for it. Try your code without prefetch.

Comment: I tried without the prefecth, it didnt fix it. I'll try and setting a ttl.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the `cache` property for `remote` since this is using `jQuery.ajax()` under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the Local storage localStorage.clear();