# How do I use a for loop with localStorage to remove an item?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I try to remove specific data from localStorage and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clear-localstorage) question.

One of the answers seems to use localStorage as an array but I don't have jQuery. To find the specific key (and value) I try to use a for loop:

```
localStorage.setItem("order", 1);
for(var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++){ 
    var item=localStorage[i];
    if (item == 'order')  
    {
        alert(item);
        // I want to inspect the value...
        // and then remove it
        localStorage.removeItem(item);
    }
}
```

This code never alerts and the value `order` is still there.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to remove the key-value pair whose value is "order"?

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Why not just `localStorage.removeItem('order');` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to get done. they key `order` should no longer be in the localStorage

Comment: @ccnokes the key and the value should be inspected for removal.

Comment: If you need to inspect the key and it's contents, `localStorage.getItem('order')` will return the key's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage is an object, you can loop through it like this

```
localStorage.setItem("order", 1);

for (var attr in localStorage){
   if (attr == 'order') {
       alert(localStorage[attr]);
       localStorage.removeItem(attr);
   }
}
```

Though there is no reason to loop, as you can simply call

```
localStorage.removeItem('order');
```

if you already know the key's name!

Answer (score 1):

To remove a certain key-value-pair from localStorage, **use [`Storage.removeItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) with the correct key**:

```
localStorage.removeItem('order');
```

There is no need to loop through the items.