# How can I detect url change in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is to flush `localStorage` when user move to other page.

For example, let say I'm currently in http://foo.com/accounts/mypage.

When user moves to url, http://foo.com/album, I want to flush `localStorage`.

This is my `JQuery` script.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    if ((window.location.pathname).indexOf('mypage') < 0) {
        localStorage.flush();
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work......

Any other nice idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clear-localstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `click` handler to your links, like this:

```
var lastLink = "";
$("body").on("click", "a", function() {
    lastLink = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

This `click` will run before the `unload` event and you will be able to use `lastLink` as your value. Just make sure you take into account relative urls as well.

```
//TODO: implement function isMine
$(window).unload(function() {
    if (isMine(lastLink)) {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
});
```

Comment: What a awesome idea!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Please try this

Comment: Ah that was my mistake. I change it to `clear()` but it doesn't seem flush the localstorage.

Comment: @user3595632, what is the result of (window.location.pathname).indexOf('mypage') ?

Comment: Now I know what's the problem. `window.location.pathname` shows current url, not url i'm heading to.. That's the reason... I need to know what is the next url

Comment: @user3595632, how are users going to next url from your page?

Comment: Click link or something... I google it and it seems like there is no way to get url user is heading to.

Comment: @user3595632, then check out my answer