# Delete Entire Local Storage Object

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Is there a way to remove all local storage properties at once, or do you have to go through and remove each separate property?

```
<script>localStorage = null</script>
```

Something along those lines.
I'm trying to future proof my website; I have a form which I want people to be able to leave and come back to later on, but once they have submitted it, the form data should be cleared from the browser memory. So I can go through and remove each property, but that means if I later add a field, I have to adjust the code on the submit page.

Comment: Use
localStorage.clear(); Said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7667973/7259765)

Comment: You can only clear local storage that you set yourself (unless you are using devtool).

Comment: Thank you, Marcelo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `clear` to delete entire `localStorage` object:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Check out below link for `clear()` and other methods of localStorage :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear