# Chrome caching page when pressing previous button

Tags: google-chrome, caching, vuejs2

i have a page that displays a list with vuejs, the user can do some update on this list (filters). Whenever he go to another page and then click the back button on the browser, there are still the old parameters (filters), he needs tu press refresh to get it right. 
These information are sent from the PHP controller, and are corrects.

Is there a way to prevent browser caching ? i found other topics on the same problem, but no answer was really fine (mostly force page reload, which is not really fine for UX)

do you know any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the cookies and local storage objects, should work see here:
[Clearing localStorage in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clearing-localstorage-in-javascript)